# Selecting a column in RDD

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I am trying to select a particular column from an RDD data. My data looks like this:

```
colA | colB
1    | cat,bat
2    | cat
3    | horse,elephant, mouse
```

I want to extract colB which is of varying length. I tried doing:

```
coldata = rdd.map(lambda x: x[1])
```

That extracts only `cat,cat,horse`
I want the extracted data to be:

```
colB
cat,bat
cat
horse,elephant,mouse
```

I create the RDD by  doing the following:

```
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
data = sc.textFile("filename").map(lambda line: line.split(","))
```

Comment: Can you show how rdd is created?

Comment: I have added the code to my original post. Thanks.

Comment: ok, and how colA and colB are separated? I assume by comma `,`?

Comment: Yes they are separated by a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after discussing in comments I found out that your columns has comma as delimiter. At the same time you have comma to separate values in "colB" column. In your script you're trying to parse columns by splitting them by comma. So do either use semicolon(or anything else as delimiter for columns) or change delimiter for values in colB:

file:

```
colA;colB
1;cat,bat
2;cat
3;horse,elephant, mouse
```

Then use this code to get RDD:

```
rdd = sc.textFile("filename").map(lambda line: line.split(";"))
```